# Code is showing a error when run with gradle

Tags: angular, gradle

```
<jhi-item-count [page]="page" [total]="totalItems" [itemsPerPage]="itemsPerPage"></jhi-item-count>
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/main/webapp/app/entities/product/list/product.component.ts:16:16
    16   templateUrl: './product.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component ProductComponent.


Error: src/main/webapp/app/entities/product/list/product.component.html:98:37 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'total' since it isn't a known property of 'jhi-item-count'.
1. If 'jhi-item-count' is an Angular component and it has 'total' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'jhi-item-count' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

98       <jhi-item-count [page]="page" [total]="totalItems" [itemsPerPage]="itemsPerPage"></jhi-item-count>
                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/main/webapp/app/entities/product/list/product.component.ts:16:16
    16   templateUrl: './product.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component ProductComponent.


Error: src/main/webapp/app/entities/product/list/product.component.html:98:58 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'itemsPerPage' since it isn't a known property of 'jhi-item-count'.
1. If 'jhi-item-count' is an Angular component and it has 'itemsPerPage' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'jhi-item-count' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

98       <jhi-item-count [page]="page" [total]="totalItems" [itemsPerPage]="itemsPerPage"></jhi-item-count>
                                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/main/webapp/app/entities/product/list/product.component.ts:16:16
    16   templateUrl: './product.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component ProductComponent.


Error: src/main/webapp/app/entities/product/list/product.component.html:103:11 - error TS2322: Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.

103         [(page)]="page"
              ~~~~

  src/main/webapp/app/entities/product/list/product.component.ts:16:16
    16   templateUrl: './product.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component ProductComponent.
```

Comment: can you edit your question using a good format? I'm confused reading

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).